# Laravel send data from one model to another inside a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to send the data (`price`) in my example to the view but inside `foreach`.
In my project, I have product data (`title`, `img`, etc.) in one table from Database.

But each product has a lot of variants and I put the variants to another table.
In the `view`, I have `foreach` which loops me `12` products.

I need to put the `price` inside each `product`.

The problem is to define each product's `id` in my controller.

**products.blade.php:**

```html
    @foreach($products as $product) 

    <div> {{ here I need to put the price }} </div>

    <div> {{ $product->slug }} </div>

    @endforeach
```

**ProductsController.php:**

```
    // all prices for my variants
    $variants_prices = Variants
                           ::where('product_slug', '=', $slug)
                           ->get('attribute_price');

    // minimum price
    $min_price = $variants_prices
                     ->where('attribute_price', $variants_prices->min('attribute_price'))
                     ->first();

    // take value of minimum price from all variants
    $pdt_min_price = $min_price->attribute_price;

    return view('products.index')
               ->with('pdt_min_price', $pdt_min_price);
```

I need to have something like this in my `blade` file:

[image]

I will be very glad if somebody will help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a relationship in your model between Product and Variant

in your `Product` model:

```
function variant()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Variant', 'foreign_key');
}
```

then you can get the variant using:

```
$products = Product::with(['variant'])->get();
```

then at the loop your can access the variant using its key:

```
{{ $product->variant[$key]['price'] }}
```